# Sequelize custom validation - unable to access all fields in entity

Tags: javascript, sql, database, validation, sequelize.js

I attempted to create a model in sequelize (say has 3 attributes, attrA, B, and C) with some custom validation logic. [This tutorial](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html) helped me get most of it set up:

```
const Model = Sequelize.define('model', {
  attrA: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
  attrB: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
  attrC: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
}, {
  validate: {
    someValidationLogic() {
       // Do something with attrA,B,C
       // if (this.attrA ... this.attrB ... this.attrC) throw new Error..
    }
  }
})
```

In the application logic however, only say, 2 out of the 3 attributes (A and B) need to be updated:

```
Model.update(
  {
    attrA: 'foo', 
    attrB: 'bar'
  }, {
  where: {
      id: 1,
  },
  returning: true,
})
```

This results in that when the custom validation logic being called, in the `this` object accessed in the function, only `attrA` and `attrB` are defined in `this`, and attrC remained undefined. This causes the validation logic to fail because attrC cannot be read. Is there any way I can get the object visible from `someValidationLogic()` to have all attributes populated? Or should this "validation" shouldn't have been validation logic at all and should've been done on the application level?

Answer (score 0):

Your validation logic could take in account the possibility of `attrC` not being defined :

```
validate: {
    someValidationLogic() {
        if (this.attrA !== 'undefined' && this.attrA === 'forbidden value' ) {
            // throw new Error
        }     
    }
}
```

But if your validation includes checking the provided values against current database values, then you would better handle this in the application layer : first recover the current database record, manipulate it as needed, then save it to database.

Comment: Thing is i need to access `attrC` when the validation logic occurs on update. For example, if a user tries to set adult content filter off, a flag gets sent in for the update. I would like to validate by accessing the dob of the user (stored in the same table) to see if they're older than 18 years of age

Comment: @ddolce : mm ok, well in this case you better off doing it in application logic

Comment: Thats actually the reason I wanted to do validation, as far as I know an addition fetch is much much more costly than having some sort of hook/validation on update

Comment: Yes but if you need database values for validation then you do have to fetch, there is no other way

Comment: @GMB the sequelize docs on the subject suggest otherwise: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#model-validations

Look at their validation function, bothCoordsOrNone()

Wouldn't this validation fail if an update were made on just latitude or longitude even if both values had been set previously?